# How to make this large if-statement more readable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to make the following large if-statement more readable in JavaScript.

Any ideas?

```
if ( Tools.Array.contains( that.pAutocompleteAliasUsed[i], this.currentString) !== false  &&
    ( this.autocomplete.list.length === 0 ) || ( this.currentString.toLowerCase() !== this.autocomplete.list[0].target.alias.toLowerCase() ) )
{
    make something
}
```

Comment: Define 'more readable.' What's the problem you're having with the current version?

Comment: depend upon your feasibility, there are many ways to accomplish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do to make things more readable is to extract the various logical tests out of the if statement. It is much easier to read a single statement and then nicely named boolean parameters in the if test.

I have done this for the first test in this example, I have had a go with the other others, but you could name them better than me as you know what they are testing.

```
var toolsContainsString = Tools.Array.contains(that.pAutocompleteAliasUsed[i], this.currentString) !== false;
var isAutoCompleteEmpty = this.autocomplete.list.length === 0;
var isTargetMatch = this.currentString.toLowerCase() !== this.autocomplete.list[0].target.alias.toLowerCase();

if (toolsContainsString && (isAutoCompleteEmpty || isTargetMatch)) {
    //make something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 if( Tools.Array.contains( that.pAutocompleteAliasUsed[i], this.currentString) !== false  &&
        ( this.autocomplete.list.length === 0 ) || 
        ( this.currentString.toLowerCase() !== this.autocomplete.list[0].target.alias.toLowerCase() )
   )
 {
          // something
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

When you have complex test, it is a good practice to (1) extract parts of the test in well defined functions and (2) to give these functions good names that explains the purpose of the function.

In that way it is enough to read the method name to understand what a function is doing and returning.

```
 if (isAutoCompleteAliasUsed(i, currentString) 
          && notEmptyOrFirst(this.autocomplete, currentString){
     // make something
 }

 function isAutoCompleteAliasUsed(index, currentString){
     return Tools.Array.contains(that.pAutocompleteAliasUsed[i], currentString);
 }

 function notEmptyOrFirst(autocomplete,currentString){
     return autocomplete.list.length === 0 
        || (currentString.toLowerCase() !== autocomplete.list[0].target.alias.toLowerCase() );
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't really make it shorter because you got all kind of variables. But what you can do is something like, which makes it more readable:

```
var list = this.autocomplete.list,
    currentString = this.currentString,
    containsCurrentString = Tools.Array.contains( that.pAutocompleteAliasUsed[i], currentString);

if ( containsCurrentString !== false  &&
        ( list.length === 0 ) || ( currentString.toLowerCase() !== list[0].target.alias.toLowerCase() ) )
{
    // make something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var bListEmpty  = !!this.autocomplete.list.length,
    sCurrent = this.currentString.toLowerCase(),
    sTarget  = this.autocomplete.list[0].target.alias.toLowerCase(),
    bContains   = Tools.Array.contains(that.pAutocompleteAliasUsed[i], this.currentString),
    bSameString = (sCurrent === sTarget);

if (bContains && bListEmpty || bSameString) {
    // do something
}
```

or

```
if (Tools.Array.contains( that.pAutocompleteAliasUsed[i], this.currentString) !== false 
        && this.autocomplete.list.length === 0
        || this.currentString.toLowerCase() !== this.autocomplete.list[0].target.alias.toLowerCase())
{
    // do something
}
```